# what is scope and transit on request?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using .NET Core API..
I have below code... which is return a GUID in response...
my question is when I tried from POSTMAN.. THIS url https://localhost:44362/weatherforecast

here I am clicking SEND  in post man, and in each time..
I have tired with scope for testing , and transit for testing..
my question
**here in scope this should return same unique ID on SEND, unit I close browser?**
in in Transit it should return different GUID from first SEND , second SEND like wise...

*Not sure how this treated the same request in SCOPE of service in .NET Core API*

my code is

```
            IOperationTransient transientOperation,
            IOperationScoped scopedOperation,
            IOperationSingleton singletonOperation,
            IOperationSingletonInstance singletonInstanceOperation)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _operationService = operationService;
            _transientOperation = transientOperation;
            _scopedOperation = scopedOperation;
            _singletonOperation = singletonOperation;
            _singletonInstanceOperation = singletonInstanceOperation;
        }

  [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = _scopedOperation.OperationId.ToString()// Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
        }
 public interface IOperation
    {
        Guid OperationId { get; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a brief explanation about services lifetime in .NET:

Lifetime Singleton: When injecting a Singleton service its reference will always be the same during the lifetime of the application.

Lifetime Scoped: A scoped service is created once per scope. In AspNet, the default scope is the web request. So if you inject a Scoped Service IMyScopedService into two or more classes (e.g. UsersController(IUsersService, IMyScopedService), UsersService(IMyScopedService)) the reference of IMyScopedService will be the same within the same web request.

Lifetime Transient: A transient service is instantied every time the IoC container injects it into a constructor

Answer (score 0):

- **Singleton** is a single instance for the lifetime of the application domain.
- **Scoped** is a single instance for the duration of the scoped request, which means per HTTP request in ASP.NET.
- **Transient** is a single instance per code request.

So when you define `IOperation` as **Scope**, container will create only one instance of it for your HTTP request, so it is absolutely normal that it creates one `GUID` as `OperationId` and for each of your requests returns that value and also definitely another value for other HTTP requests.

But if you define `IOperation` as **transient**, container creates for each code request an instance of `IOperation`. So each time you requests an `OperationId`,  the value will be different.

Notice: We must be careful that the program does not have "**Captive Dependency**".
Actually It occurs when a service intended to live for a short(er) amount of time gets held by a service that lives for a more extended amount of time.

Always consider the following rules when implementing dependency injection:

1. Singleton service should not depend on either a Transient service or a scoped service.
2. Scoped service should not depend on a Transient service.